# Relationships amusingly difficult to graph

Tags: examples, graphing

Long ago, when I was the student, I encountered a bunch of stories that we were asked to illustrate with graphs. I seem to remember that it was a set of around 10 examples. One involved some two quantities, like height over time, for a child in a Ferris wheel; the graph was properly sinusoidal, but many of us had a lot of trouble accepting that. A second was a story about a child walking to school, returning home to get something left behind, and then proceeding on his way, for which some students confused the curve on the graph with a path on a map.

Anyone know where I can get this activity or something of the sort? If it's amusing, that's a big plus for me.

Comment: Google "graphing stories". There are lots of videos these days. If you don't want that, you can write stories from the videos available.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of @SueVanHattum's graphing stories.
[Link](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/JuniorMath/Graphing/GRStoryGraphPractice.html).

---

[image]

---